# Alertify JS Center dialog window

Tags: javascript, css, alertify, alertifyjs

Is there a way to center the dialog windows of the Alertify Js plugin? http://alertifyjs.com

I have seen there is a property called position, but it does not support center position.

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you talking about vertical center? Because it appears to already be centered horizontally in the [demos](http://alertifyjs.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you modify the css you can achieve this:

```
.alertify .ajs-dialog {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: auto;
}
```

### Before:

[image]

### After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this is ok when the dialog is nos draggable. But when you drag the dialog, it moves to the top of the window.

Comment: Use 'autoReset', false to avoid seting the position again on window resize
 alertify.confirm('autoReset: false').set('autoReset', false);